# MySql Query returning empty result sets

Tags: mysql

Hi there i have following two tables:

**Devices Table:**

```
deviceID    accountID  InstallTime    fName         lName   
1            2          NULL          Dave          O'Riordan   
2            2          NULL          Kathrine      Hutter  
3            2          NULL          Guy           Swider
```

**a2_deal table:**

```
deviceID  companyID  contactID  stage   event   state   serverTime  clientTime  monetary
1            1          1        -1     CALL    OUT     1349445600  1349445600  4600
1           14         12        -1     CALL    OUT     1349449200 1349449200   5400
2           16         19        -1     CALL    OUT     1349445600 1349445600   4456
2           21         20        -1     CALL    OUT     1349449200 1349449200   4000
3           17         22        -1     CALL    OUT     1349447160 1349447160   12000
1            1          1         1     CALL    OUT     1349082060 1349082060   NULL
1           14         12         1     CHECK   IN      1349083380 1349083380   NULL
1            1          1         1     CHECK   IN      1349082660 1349082660   NULL
1           14         12         1     CHECK   OUT     1349085382 1349085382   NULL
1            1          1         1     CHECK   OUT     1349082700 1349082700   NULL
```

I made a query as follows:

```
SELECT deal.deviceID, devices.fName, devices.lName, SUM(event) AS visits
 FROM `a2_deal` AS deal
 LEFT JOIN `devices` AS devices ON deal.deviceID = devices.deviceID
 WHERE `event` LIKE 'CHECK' 
 AND `serverTime` >= 1349082060
 AND `serverTime` <= 1349190000
 GROUP BY deal.deviceID
 ORDER BY visits
```

it worked fine and give me results....
But when i tried to retrive the data from column  **stage** in a2_deal table based on the condition its giving me no results(Empty result set)...

```
SELECT deal.deviceID, devices.fName, devices.lName, SUM(stage) AS closes
FROM `a2_deal` AS deal
LEFT JOIN `devices` AS devices ON deal.deviceID = devices.deviceID
WHERE `stage` =  -1
AND `serverTime` >= 1349082060
AND `serverTime` <= 1349190000
GROUP BY deal.deviceID
ORDER BY closes
```

Any suggestions what i am doing wrong... thank YOu

Comment: Instead of using two `AND`s, switch to `BETWEEN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query with

```
WHERE `stage` =  -1
AND `serverTime` >= 1349082060
AND `serverTime` <= 1349190000
```

didn't return any results because all values with `stage = -1` have time out of the defined range.

On a side note, you can use `serverTime BETWEEN <start> AND <end>`.

Comment: yes your are right ..i found it after a long struggle... thank you